# iOS: UITableView row swipe from left for more options in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swipe-gesture, uitableviewrowaction

I am using iOS 9 and Swift 2.2

How do I modify below function/add new function to make some options to swipe from left?

I want to add a few options to be shown on swiping from both left and right. I am sure we do not need any third party API to do this, but I want to be able to modify the below code to achieve the required functionality.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]?
{
    let MorAknOpnVar = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "More")
    {   action, index in

        print("More OpnBtnKlk")
        /* CodTdo */
    }
    MorAknOpnVar.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

    let NamAknOpnVar = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "NamTtl")
    {   action, index in

        print("NamTtl OpnBtnKlk")
        /* CodTdo */
    }
    NamAknOpnVar.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

    let ShrAknOpnVar = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Share")
    {   action, index in

        print("Share OpnBtnKlk")
        /* CodTdo */
    }
    ShrAknOpnVar.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    return [ShrAknOpnVar, NamAknOpnVar, MorAknOpnVar]
}
```

Comment: This might help you for swipe from the left: https://www.raywenderlich.com/77974/making-a-gesture-driven-to-do-list-app-like-clear-in-swift-part-1

Comment: Thanks for the solution.
Am new to stackoverflow and do not have enough reputations yet, So kindly vote for my question up, so i can vote for your ans